# C++ UI form on top of C application

Tags: c++, c, forms, visual-studio, win32gui

I Currently have a C win32 application in place, I am wanting to make a GUI to communicate and call various api command in my application. In visual studio I select project -> add new items -> [C++ -> windows form] and a nice form pops up. My question is how do I make calls from the form.h file produced. A nice example to see would be seeing a gui modifying a value and that value simply printing out in the console (a function in the application external from the form.h file). If not, any links related would be nice

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to call C from C++ or vice versa?

Comment: C from C++, which I believe is possible. so a C++ form GUI on top of a C application

Answer (score 0):

Define header file for your C library with C++ guards.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


int my_c_function1(void);
int my_c_function2(void);
struct my_c_struct { ... };
void my_c_function3(struct my_c_struct *p);
... 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It is important that all type and function declarations are between #ifdef blocks.

Those blocks tell C++ compiler that the data types and functions from that scope belong to C language and require C ABI bindings.

So you would be able to use those types and functions without error in both C and C++ source files.